# how to delete records if not exists in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, angular, sequelize.js

I am struggling to Sequelize with a certain condition. Here is the code:

```js
let apiList = [{id: 1, name: "A"}, {id: 3, name: "C"}];
let currentList = Model.findAll(); // [{id: 1, name: "A"}, {id: 2, name: "B"}, {id: 3, name: "C"}];

// I want to delete unmatching records with IDs from apiList
// Like I want to have these records only in my model db.
// [{id: 1, name: "A"}, {id: 3, name: "C"}];
```

My end goal is I want to have a newly updated `currentList` which does not have any unmatching IDs with `apiList`.

Is there any way like using `destroy()` method in Sequelize?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use [Op](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#operators) in Sequelize to delete unmatching record in database

```
await Model.destroy({
  where: { id: {[Op.not]: [1, 3] } }, // Change the [1, 3] with variable that contain Id that match
});
```